# Facebook Messaging API help required

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to send messages to people who are in a group (can be multiple groups).And, I want to send them messages as a user using facebook API. The user account that I'll be using is a member of those groups.

Is it possible ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

The only API to send messages is the Messenger API, and that is for messages between a page and a user only.

There is no user-to-user message API.

Comment: Can I send messages as a group to users ?

Comment: No, you can not.